# oracle apex can't creat or edit any "List of values"

Tags: apex

When I tried to create a new list of values
I got an error as shown in the images below
[Insert image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHDyq.png)
And I also got the same error when I tried to modify any existing list of values.
What am I missing?? Help me.

i installed apex locally  so i tried to restart database and reinstall apex but I got same error